# Missing Back Button from UIViewController in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, back

I have a tabbed table view controller and in one of the tabs, I'm clicking on a cell which takes me to a View Controller instead of another Table view.

It's all embedded in a UINavigationController but when I push, I do not get the back button with the name of the previous view controller on it.

In the other tabs, I click on a cell and push to another table view and that works fine, but it does not in this case.

I've been reading up on this and have certainly set the title of my new view controller in the viewDidLoad of that detail class.

The back button functionality works, it takes me back to the previous controller, but it just doesn't show me the label.

Any assistance on this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If the title of the pushed view controller is too big, then only the back arrow icon will be displayed, without any text. That is the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Unfortunately I'm not getting the title or the arrow :(

Answer (score 0):

do you checked the Shows Navigation Bar item in the attribute inspector of that particular navigation controller

[image]

or you can programmatically add the statement

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - the top is enabled and I added the code to the viewDidLoad of the view controller I'm displaying and still nothing - the back button works, but there's no text on it or back arrow.. so weird

Comment: did u set the title property of that  previous table controller??

Comment: I did.. and the title is showing.. but the back button and back word isn't .. so weird because in other places in the app, it's working perfectly - I've even removed this view and recreated it but to the same effect

Comment: are u using a custom backbutton?? or using any code like...   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = ...
or

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;                               while showing the title the back word will not be there