# Back button suddenly stopped appearing in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I built a simple 'About' page for my app that is simply a webView with local HTML. My Settings are contained within a separate storyboard and the AboutViewController is a view within that storyboard.

When the AboutViewController is presented it no longer shows a back button to go back to the settings.

This has worked perfectly fine for the past two weeks and has suddenly stopped working today. Is there a better way to push the view onto the navigation controller?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)

let aboutViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutViewController, animated: true)

self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

I have a slightly older version of my app running on my phone and it looks like this:
 [image: old (correct) view]

And now it looks like this: 
[image: new (incorrect) view]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469089/missing-back-button-from-uiviewcontroller-in-a-navigation-controller

Comment: check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394194/swift-cant-show-back-button-after-hiding-it

Comment: Neither of those helped sorry. This is so weird, it was working an hour ago and I haven't changed any code relating to either View.

Answer (score 0):

Well a workaround is to put it back yourself.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back")
}

func back()
{
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```